# How to tune this CASE expression?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a big query that has multiple Joins as below. 
Now I have to tune this query.

Current Logic is: If AppealOutcome Code = F/D/P then Insert ReAdjustedClaimControlNumber.

I need to change my Logic as: For Disposition F/D/P, When ReAdjustmentId is empty from MonthlyApepalFile, Use AdjustmentID. If AdjustmentId is also Empty, Use ClaimControlNumber.

Can anyone please throw any shortcuts?

```
Insert into rec.RecoveryClaims (ClaimControlKey, ClaimOutcomeCode, ClaimControlNumber )
select 
             A.ClaimControlKey
             ,ClaimOutcomeCode

            ,CASE   WHEN E.AppealOutcomecode = 'F' THEN E.ReadjustedClaimControlNumber
                    WHEN E.AppealOutcomecode = 'D' THEN E.ReadjustedClaimControlNumber
                    WHEN E.AppealOutcomecode = 'P' THEN E.ReadjustedClaimControlNumber
                    ELSE E.AdjustedClaimControlNumber
                    END  
FROM rec.RecoveryClaims A 
INNER JOIN @ExistingRecoveryClaimControlKey b 
    on a.RecoveryClaimControlKey = b.RecoveryClaimControlKey
INNER JOIN occ.Claims C 
    on c.ClaimControlKey = A.ClaimControlKey
INNER JOIN @OutputRecoveryCases D 
    on D.CaseID = C.CaseId  
INNER JOIN @NewClaimControlNumbers E 
    ON C.CaseId = E.CaseID 
    AND A.ClaimControlKey = E.ClaimControlKey
```

Comment: Can you show us the current execution plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collapse that `CASE` statement by using `IN`:

```
,CASE   WHEN E.AppealOutcomecode IN ('F', 'D', 'P') 
        THEN E.ReadjustedClaimControlNumber
        ELSE E.AdjustedClaimControlNumber
END
```

Next, if I understand your requirements, the next portion would look like:

```
,CASE   WHEN Disposition IN ('F', 'D', 'P') 
        THEN COALESCE(ReAdjustmentId , AdjustmentID, ClaimControlNumber)
END
```

EDIT:

If the strings are empty instead of `NULL`, you can use [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) in conjunction with `COALESCE`:

```
,CASE   WHEN Disposition IN ('F', 'D', 'P') 
        THEN COALESCE(
            NULLIF(ReAdjustmentId, '') , 
            NULLIF(AdjustmentID, ''), 
            NULLIF(ClaimControlNumber, '')
        )
END
```

Comment: But How about if they are Empty String?

Comment: @Rita Please see my edit... `NULLIF` should solve this scenario.